# Como selecionar automaticamente item de menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Tenho o seguinte código:

http://jsfiddle.net/xktjk03w/

HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title> Teste </title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">  
<div class="navbar-inner">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="brand" href="#">Home</a>        
      <ul class="nav">
       <li class="active"><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>         
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>          
      </ul>
  </div>     
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li><a href="#tab1-0" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab1-1" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab1-2" data-toggle="tab">Tab 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab1-3" data-toggle="tab">Tab 4</a></li>        
        </ul>                
 </div>
</div>  
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid"> 
    <div class="tab-content">
          <div class="tab-pane" id="tab1-0">
               <ul class="nav nav-list">
                  <li class="nav-header">Menu 1</li>
               <li><a href="#" id="menuItemUm">Menu Item tab 1</a></li>                      
              </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2-0">
             <ul class="nav nav-list">
             <li class="nav-header">Menu 2</li>
             <li><a href="#" id="menuItemDois">Menu Item tab 2</a></li>                      
             </ul>
          </div>                       
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
        </div>      
  <div class="span9" id="divPrincipal">          
    <div class="row-fluid">      
        <iframe id="if" frameborder="0"></iframe>  
      <div class="span9"></div>
    </div>
  </div><!--/span-->
 </div><!--/row-->

 <hr/>

</div><!--/.fluid-container-->
</body>
```

JS:

```
$("ul.nav-tabs a").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();  
  $(this).tab('show');
});
$("#menuItem").click(function() {
$("#if").attr('src', 'http://Exemplo/Example/main.php');
});
```

Exemplo: Eu quero que quando clicar no Menu 1 e clicar na tab 1, selecionar automaticamente o primeiro item de menu que tiver e carregar seu conteúdo.

Já tentei fazer com a class ".active" mas ele só fica selecionado, não carrega.

Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque no seu iframe uma tag name, logo após quando clicar no link coloque o target para o name do iframe.

```
 <a href="http://www.hiago.me" target="teste" >Teste</a>
 <iframe id="if" name="teste" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

> Lembro também que faltou incluir o jquery no head do seu HMTL

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

> Faça o teste se esta entrado na rotina do .click(), coloque um alert para certificar que está chegando até la a execução de seu código.

```
$("#menuItem").click(function() {
   alert('Chegou !!'); // Para testar o evento...
   $("#if").attr('src','http://Exemplo/Example/main.php');
});
```

Comment: acho que me expressei mal, olha só o print: http://s29.postimg.org/fd7ywco53/menu1.png
Quando eu clicar na Tab 1, ele é pra selecionar automaticamente o Menu Item 1, e carregar o conteúdo no iframe. Dessa forma que vc falou não consegui.

Comment: Assim entendi, você poderia subir seu código no JSFiddler ou em outro local para eu analisar como poderia ser feito? Tem como fazer com jQuery porém preciso ver sua estrutura...

Comment: Olá Hiago, eu já resolvi meu problema. Optei por fazer sem tabs. Obrigado.

Comment: Por nada que bom que ajudou..